# Best way to deal with erroneous message "There is already an object named '#Tablename' in the database."

Tags: sql-server

I have a recursive stored procedure running on SQL server 2005.  I tested it and it works well.  But when I tried to add another capability to it I get the message:

> There is already an object named '#BOM' in the database.

The problem is that I need to create the initial temp table 2 different ways depending on parameters.  The temp table is used for a set of reports the expand a BOM (Bill Of Materials).  The BOM can consist of parts that are sub-assemblies that have thier own BOMs.  In the simplest form I need this to work:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExpandBOMTestError2]
(
    @Similiar bit = 0
)AS
BEGIN

    IF @Similiar = 0
        SELECT '1' As Col INTO #BOM
    ELSE
        SELECT '2' As Col INTO #BOM

    SELECT * FROM #BOM

END
```

I even tried this, although I would prefer to avoid something this ugly and cluttering I would accept it if it would work:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExpandBOMTestError]
(
    @Similiar bit = 0
)AS
BEGIN

    IF @Similiar = 0
        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#BOM')) IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE #BOM
            SELECT '1' As Col INTO #BOM
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#BOM')) IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE #BOM
            SELECT '2' As Col INTO #BOM
        END

    SELECT * FROM #BOM

END
```

I am also enclosing the original procedure incase anyone wants to provide alternate solutions that may work in my stripped down example but not in real production code.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExpandBOMList]
(
    @ItemID varchar(100),
    @Level int,
    @EffectiveDate datetime = null,
    @ExcludeIgnoreCost bit = 0,
    @MaxBOMLevel int = 99,
    @Similiar bit = 0
)AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @NewLevel int

    IF @Level = 0
        BEGIN
            IF @Similiar = 0
                SELECT @ItemID AS SubAssembly, @ItemID AS Component, Null AS EffectiveDate, 1 AS QPA, 0 AS BOMLevel INTO #BOM
            ELSE
                SELECT IMA_ItemID AS SubAssembly, IMA_ItemID AS Component, Null AS EffectiveDate, 1 AS QPA, 0 AS BOMLevel INTO #BOM FROM Item WHERE IMA_ItemID LIKE @ItemID + '%' 
            SET @NewLevel = @Level + 1
            EXEC ExpandBOMList @ItemID, @NewLevel, @ExcludeIgnoreCost, @MaxBOMLevel
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT #BOM SELECT ItemParent.IMA_ItemID, ItemChild.IMA_ItemID, Null, PST_QtyPerAssy, @Level
                            FROM ProductStructureHeader
                                JOIN ProductStructure ON PST_PSH_RecordID = PSH_RecordID
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN Item AS ItemParent ON PSH_IMA_RecordID = ItemParent.IMA_RecordID 
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN Item AS ItemChild ON PST_IMA_RecordID = ItemChild.IMA_RecordID 
                                JOIN #BOM ON ItemParent.IMA_ItemID = Component AND BOMLevel = @Level - 1
                            WHERE PST_QtyPerAssy <> 0 AND PST_EffStopDate IS NULL AND BOMLevel <= @MaxBOMLevel

            IF @@rowcount > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @Level = @Level + 1
                    EXEC ExpandBOMList @ItemID, @Level, @ExcludeIgnoreCost, @MaxBOMLevel
                END
        END

        IF @Level = 0
            SELECT Component AS ItemID, IMA_ItemName AS ItemName, BOMLevel
                FROM #BOM
                    JOIN Item on IMA_ItemID = Component


END
```

I hope someone has a good idea before I have to make this real ugly.

Comment: A recursive stored procedure??? This looks like you could replace this with a recursive cte instead. Would be WAY simpler to deal with than this. To make your code work with procedures like you are doing will require dynamic sql all over the place. This will quickly get out of hand and become a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Sean This does not require any dynamic SQL, that is simply untrue.  SO works best when people stick to the facts and leave their opinions at the door  Remember, just because something is WAY simpler for you does not mean is it way simpler for everyone.  Plus speculating does not help anyone else who comes here looking for answers.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your table structure, sample data and desired output. I would happy to demonstrate how you could use a recursive cte for this. Then when you have posted all the facts required to help you I will stick to those facts. Since they were not all posted I had to speculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple example I would do the following.  I will look at the original procedure you posted and update my answer if I can offer any advice on that.  It looks like some pretty complicated stuff  you are doing.  I would need time and data to try to figure something out other than what you are doing.  Gut feeling is that using hierarchy might be appropriate.

Editing my original answer to account for recursive nature.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExpandBOMTestError2]
(
    @Similiar bit = 0
)AS
BEGIN    
  IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#BOM')) IS NULL
      Create Table #BOM (Col Int)
  IF @Similiar = 0
      Insert #BOM SELECT '1' 
  ELSE
      Insert #BOM SELECT '2' 

  SELECT * FROM #BOM
END
```

Comment: Awesome!  I cant believe I didnt think of it.  My brain must've been full when I hit that error, works perfect!